# How do I change the default sounds for the calendar warning function in CE 5.0?

Tags: windows-ce, audio

I have an old Moto Q that I would like to change the default alarm sound in the Calendar function.  Right now, it seems to pick up the Alarm4.mid file in the Windows directory, which is embedded in ROM, so the filenames can't be changed.  Is there a way to change the file pointer in the Calendar function to another file or is there another way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings/Sounds and change the Reminder sound to an existing or new sound.